# Android Login validatation API

Tags: android

I have a simple login with tokens through a api, I get the token from the server and save it to SharedPreferences. My question is what am I supposed to do now, my idea was to check if the user has a token to then skip the login process. I have the login logic in my MainActivity.java just in the onCreate, I know it shouldn't be there but where should I set it up?

This is how I take the response from the server and save it

```
User user = response.body();

if (user != null) {
    int id = user.getId();
    String name = user.getName();
    String lastname = user.getLastname();
    String maidenname = user.getMaidenname();
    String card = user.getCard();
    String scard = user.getScard();
    String email = user.getEmail();
    String token = user.getToken();

    User current = new User(id, name, lastname, maidenname, card, scard, email, token);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putString(TOKEN, current.getToken());
    editor.apply();
```

I created a User Model for the current user that is logged in, should I save that somewhere else or how can I access it from all activities later on?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store some user information and access it from any activity, I believe the best way is storing it in SharedPreferences and creating a helper class to get and set these values in preferences. For example:

```
public class SharedPreferencesHelper {

    private static final String USER_ID = "USER_ID";
    private static final String USER_NAME = "USER_NAME";
    private static final String USER_LAST_NAME = "USER_LAST_NAME";
    //.... etc for all User members

    private static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context context) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    public static User getUser(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(context); 
        int id = sp.getInt(USER_ID, -1);
        String name = sp.getString(USER_NAME, null);
        String lastName = sp.getString(USER_LAST_NAME, null);
        // etc for all User members

        return new User(id, name, lastName, ....);
    }

    public static void setUser(Context context, User user) {
        if (user != null) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor() editor = getSharedPreferences(context).edit();
            editor.putInt(USER_ID, user.getId());
            editor.putString(USER_NAME, user.getName());
            editor.putString(USER_LAST_NAME, user.getLastName());
            ... (etc, for all user class members)

            editor.apply();
        }
    }

    // the remove method you could use, for example, if users logs out
    public static void removeUser(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor() editor = getSharedPreferences(context).edit();
        editor.remove(USER_ID);
        editor.remove(USER_NAME);
        // etc for all user members stored in SharedPreferences

        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

This class methods could be called from any activity in your app. I believe is the safest way of storing and retrieving values like these. You only have to be careful to properly remove and store these information when user logs in and out.

I hope this helps! If you have any other questions, feel free to complement (and please post your complete code).

Comment: I'm getting a couple errors, in the getUser method on the last line, I get this 
`User() in User cannot be applied to: Change 1st parameter of method 'User' from 'int' to 'String'`
And in setUser method in the line `editor.putString(USER_ID, user.getId());` it says `found 'int' required 'String'`

In my User model I have the user_id as a int, should I change it?

Comment: Sorry, I had not realized that `id` was of type `int`. You should get and set the User values in SharedPreferences accordingly to their class types. Since `id` is of type `int` you have to use `editor.putInt` and `sp.getInt` methods. I edited the answer with this correction. I hope it works now!

Comment: Great, that works, how would I use this in the Login part? Just call it?

Comment: Also what should I pass as the Context parameter?

Comment: You should pass your current activity, from which you are making the call. In this case, your MainActivity, like this: `SharedPreferencesHelper.getUser(MainActivity.this)`;

Comment: oh I had just put `this` no wonder, what do you suggest I do for the login should I move all that logic to another class?

Comment: Hi Nancy! Glad it worked! I don't understand exactly what's your concern. Maybe you could post your complete Activity code so we could understand better what you are doing and what's your concern? Would be great if you could create a separate SO question for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210826/discussion-between-nancy-and-caue-jannini).